# Off-topic twice in filter menu

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, vote-to-close

Both on [Ask Ubuntu](https://Askubuntu.com) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com) I noticed that the word "off-topic" is now appearing twice in the filter when working the close queue:

[image: Off-topic²]

whereas this was not the case yesterday.

Is this a [bug or a feature](https://blog.codinghorror.com/thats-not-a-bug-its-a-feature-request/)?

Comment: Reproduced here on Meta. The queue is empty, so it’s not because there are so many posts flagged as off-topic. ;)

Comment: MSO [cross-site duplicate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384660/teams-bug-causes-off-topic-close-reason-to-show-twice-in-close-review-filterin) (as answer says, this has to do with Teams, and the Teams dev team is active there)

Comment: I'm having a look at this right now. This is indeed something we're working on for Teams at the moment - seems like it slipped through to other parts of the site as well. Sorry about that!

Comment: Errare Humanum Est... **:-)**

Comment: There should be a "duplicate" item in that place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you for spotting this. This was indeed an unintended side-effect when introducing a new close reason for Teams. I didn't have in mind that our moderator tools consider all close reasons when showing filter options.

Sorry for the confusion. The problem's fixed now and the second *off-topic* option is gone.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Just something small, better add "at Stack Overflow" in your about me, since the developer story is visible only on SO. Here it looks like you're just an ordinary software developer, since it doesn't say where. Cheers! :-)

Comment: Thanks. That's a fair point, I've updated my profile :)

Comment: Thanks for that.  Would you care to add a [status-completed]  [here as well?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/q/18595/344926)

Answer (score 7):

That's a bug due to Teams.

As can be seen in [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1042309/closereasontypes), the second off topic reason is a new close reason meant for Teams:

> [image]

(If you'll view the filters source code you'll see the input ID is `filter-closereason-201`)

So, this close reason should not appear on the regular Q&A sites.

Comment: I'm a member of a Team and the only close reason option I can see is to close as duplicate, as has been the case for a long time. I [reposted](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/384660/teams-bug-causes-off-topic-close-reason-to-show-twice-in-close-review-filterin) this bug report on MSO since the Teams development team is active there.

Comment: Thanks @Sonic let's hope they'll take a look.

Comment: *You are a wizard!*:  I didn't even look at the code nor the data...  **;-)  +1**